# How to enable sub menu on the global menu?

Tags: navigation, sharepoint-online

We recently signed up for Office 365 and are in the process of building out oure SharePoint site.

We started with the default site, a Team Site and have built out the following site map:

- Site

  - Sub Site 1
  - Sub Site 2

    - Sub Site 3
    - Sub Site 4
  - Sub Site 5

The main navigation appears as:

Sub Site 1 | Sub Site 2 | Sub Site 5

We would like a drop down menu to appear when the user hovers over Sub Site 2, showing the Sites under that Site.

It looks like SharePoint 2010 supports this, for the life of me I can't seem to get the settings right to make this work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Per the recommendation below ... I located the following:

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu
      ID="TopNavigationMenuV4"
      Runat="server"
      EnableViewState="false"
      DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
      AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
      UseSimpleRendering="true"
      UseSeparateCss="false"
      Orientation="Horizontal"
      StaticDisplayLevels="2"
      MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1"
      SkipLinkText=""
      CssClass="s4-tn"/>
```

It looks correct ... but menus still not displaying.

So I made those changes in the master page ... and then I checked the box below:

[image]

I do get a drop down menu, but now it seems my links are duplicated:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Find the `SharePoint:AspMenu` control with the ID *TopNavigationMenu* in the masterpage and set these values

```
StaticDisplayLevels="X"
MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="X"
```

Comment: I just want to make sure ... so there is no setting or configuration to just make this work?

Comment: Not through the SharePoint UI, no.

Comment: Can you take another look at my question ... I included the text ... it looks correct.

Comment: You need to change `MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels` to something greater than 1.

Comment: @mattruma What JamesLove said :)

Comment: I modified both the default.master and v4.master ... switch that value to 2 and still not seeing drop downs. Any other thing I need to do?

Comment: Kind of have it working ... please see my updates ... now I have double links in the navigation.

Comment: Got it! Was able to remove the duplicate items ... thanks!

Comment: This one works? Could anybody post a little details here? THANKS!

Comment: @SPbb Sure. What do you wanna know?

Comment: Cannot comment yet so I'll add a precision here; Just having the same problem right now, and trying the solution above gives me this SharePoint error: >Cannot create an object of type 'System.Int32' from its string representation 'X' for the 'StaticDisplayLevels' property. Maybe that's because I'm on SharePoint 2013 and not 2010 I don't know, but anyway, I just thought it would be nice for people facing this, to know that they'd better use precise numbers instead of "X" :)