# How to display SubSites and their SitePages via the Quick Launch Navigation Menu

Tags: navigation, quick-launch

I am looking for a solution to change the default view of the Quick Launch Navigation Menu:

- Display SubSites as root nodes;
- Display SitePages as leaves.

in the following manner:

```
-SubSite1
   -SitePage1-1
   -SitePage1-2
-SubSite2
   -SitePage2-1
   -SitePage2-2
```

Is there any built-in SiteMapProvider that allows for displaying a default menu in the required manner?

- or perhaps I should write some code that retrieves all existing SubSites/SitePages and converts the results to the hierarchical structure?
- or something else?

As a temporary solution, I have created an XML file with all SubSites and their SitePages and am filtering this content via XPath expression (using the XmlDataSouce control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly what you are asking for is available out of the box with the paid version of SharePoint. When you get you turn on the publishing infrastructure feature you get a unified "Navigation" site setting instead of separate settings for quick launch and global navigation. In this navigation setting page you can choose to show subsites and pages as items and then organize how you want them to be displayed on the quick launch.

If you don't have the publishing infrastructure site collection feature you are most likely looking at writing code. You may able to figure out which site map provider the paid version uses and see if its available for use but I have a feeling you would need the additional DLLs made available through the paid version to get it to work.

**Update - More Details:**

This site covers it pretty well: http://www.alexbruett.net/?p=285

Essentially, you will need the Site Collection Feature "SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure" activated on the site collection and on the site that you want to display the pages from will need the "SharePoint Publishing" site feature activated.

Once these are activated, configure the top level site to display navigation items below the current site and to display subsites (This gets your heading).

Then configure the subsite to show pages in the navigation. (These pages must be in the "Pages" library - in 2010 its important to note this is separate from the "Site Pages" library).

Comment: Thank you. Would you please provide a prof link to the "Publishing Infrastructure" methodology?

Comment: Updated my answer with the information requested. It doesn't give you the exact steps but it covers the new navigation features and my explanation will help you get what you want.

Comment: Note that you don't need to turn on the entire Publishing Infrastructure only for the Navigation: http://www.novolocus.com/2011/12/02/publishing-navigation-without-the-publishing/

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna check [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25257/how-to-enable-sub-menu-on-the-global-menu/25262#25262) out as it is relevant. Only difference being you'll need to find the QuickLaunch instead of the TopNavigation