# Global Navigation shows the site name as top level. Need to remove it

Tags: 2013, navigation, top-link-bar

While I was able to setup multilevel navigation from Site Settings -> Navigation but in the navigation it always shows the Site Name as first level then other pages comes on the sub level. How can I remove the Site name from the top level and make other pages visible in the top level? I am using Share Point 2013

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable sub menu on the global menu?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25257/how-to-enable-sub-menu-on-the-global-menu)

Comment: If you found your answer (as per your comment below), please post it as an answer on the question and mark it as your accepted answer. This will put this question in a correct state

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you only want to remove site name on the top of the page?

If yes, you should edit your Master Page and remove from it needed section.
You can find it at the virtual directory `_catalogs/masterpage/<master-page-name>.html` of your site.

Comment: thank you for the answer. But I solved it. It was my mistake didn't noticed you can enable and disable the site title.